# BigInteger Wrong Answer

Tags: java

I was calculating a simple combination using java, when I define the result as double, the answer seems right, only lost some precision, but when I use the BigInteger class, the answer looks just wrong at all, I don't see why it's like that, here is the code.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input the lottery sum");
    int num = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please input the available sum");
    int avail = in.nextInt();

    //double sum = 1;
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ONE;

    for (int i = avail - 1; i >= 1;i--){
        //sum = sum*(num - i) / i;
        sum = sum.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(num - i)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }

    //sum = sum * num / avail;
    sum = sum.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(num)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(avail));
    System.out.println(sum);

    in.close();
}
}
```

Comment: you should use BigDecimal instead

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] instead, showing exactly one calculation, along with expected and actual output. It seems likely that you're somehow expecting `BigInteger` to represent non-integer values, but it's hard to tell as you haven't shown the calculation involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between `double` and `BigInteger` is that one is using float-point maths, and other is using integer maths. This means that, when you using `BigInteger`, the result of every division gets truncated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're calculating, but I suspect that the integer division is what's causing the observed differences.

I suppose that you get the same result with BigInteger and a regular int for small examples.

For example:
double:
3.0/2.0 = 1.5

(Big)Integer:
3/2 = 1

If you sum over such divisions multiple times, the discrepancy gets bigger and bigger.

Take a look at BigDecimal, that may be the solution you're after to avoid this error introduced by integer divisions.